# How to call an API,say X(which consists of urls) inside of webrequest api of google chrome to block that set of url fetched from the X?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, blocking

I want to call an API,or lets say for now a JSON file residing in the same folder as that of background.js
Here is my background.js file

```
const x='*://xyz.com/';
const filter = {
 urls: [
   x,
 ],
};

const opt = ['blocking'];


window.chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(details){

/fetching data from blacklist_urls.json*/

fetch('blacklist_urls.json')
      .then(
        function(response) {
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
              response.status);
            return;
          }

          // Examine the text in the response
          response.json().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(x);
          });
        }
      )
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
      });


/end of fetching data from blacklist_urls.json*/

console.log('page blocked - ' + details.url);

return {
  cancel: true,
  };
},
filter,
opt
);
```

Here the url xyz.com is being blocked correctly.But the blacklisturls.json file is not being fetched.

Comment: chrome.webRequest won't wait for your asynchronous calls to complete so you need to read the json file at the start of the script and save it into a global variable, then use it in your onBeforeRequest listener.

Comment: I have to take the url input by the user and send it to API for some processing,and based on response,block that url.Thats why I had declared fetch inside of webrequest

Comment: You're out of luck in Chrome. Only Firefox supports asynchronous blocking response in onBeforeRequest.

Comment: @wOxxOm - Isn't possible to call `await` and obtain the content of the file within `onBeforeRequest` and then provide data URL with content as a redirect? While obtaining the content of the file prior would be definitely a better solution, sometimes we just don't know the URL before this function is called. Many sites change their javascript very often (e.g. *.../script.202103023843.js*, where the number part of the URL changes frequently)

Comment: `await` doesn't magically run code "within", it's the same old Promise underneath.